# C/C++ AQtime profiler questions

Tags: c++, profiling, aqtime

I need to profile my console program with AQ. It is in one big file (for optimizations purposes).

```
void function1();
void function2()
// etc more declarations
int main{

    //alot of loops, and function uses
    function1();
    function1();
}
```

Profiling on "Elapsed time" default profile just gives me that main is using 100% and that it took 40sec to do its job. Nothing on how much time the functions that were called inside the main took time, only how many times they were called, which says nothing.

Am I missing something in configuring AQtime as I cant find it? Would like to get how much time the functions took time to do it's job..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AQtime will only profile the routines you tell it to profile. Its startup wizard is pretty helpful in terms of helping you configure this correctly; I'd recommend paying pretty careful attention to it, but the general procedure is:

1. Create an area. Configure that area for line or routine profiling.
2. Add source files to the area. In this case, just your one file.
3. Now profile.

The general rule is that if you don't tell AQtime to instrument the routine, it will not be instrumented. There is a default area for all code in your application, but it is for routine profiling, not line profiling, only.